# Jquery drag and drop while also closing parent div?

Tags: jquery, draggable, jquery-ui-draggable

Say I have an image in a div

```
<div id="myImage"><img src="#" id="dragImage"></div>
```

I want to be able to **drag** that image using jquery .draggable and also close the parent div while still dragging the image.

I thought this would work, but it doesn't

```
$('#myImage').click(function () { 
$('#dragImage').draggable();
$('#myImage').hide();

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$( "#dragImage" ).draggable({
   drag: function(event, ui) { $('#myImage').hide();}
});
```

try this

Comment: . remove the single quote from $( "#dragImage'" ).draggable  :)

Comment: @Kanishka Panamaldeniya edited as you wished .. thanks for your quick catch up.:)

Comment: The code doesn't work?  It closes the window, but doesn't still allow the image to be grabbed.  Any ideas?

Comment: `$('#myImage').hide()` will hide your image. so you wont see the image while dragging